# Get Value from XML tag

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following code:

```
p.tel.FirstOrDefault(t => t.teltype == "mobile").ToString()
```

```html
<person>
  <name>Donald Duck</name>
  <tel teltype="voice" />
  <tel teltype="mobile">01000000</tel>
</person>
```

The c# class for the xml look like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("tel")]
public enterprisePersonTel[] tel {
    get {
        return this.telField;
    }
    set {
        this.telField = value;
    }
}
```

My code returns: enterprisePersonTel

This doesn't work

```
p.tel.FirstOrDefault(t => t.teltype == "mobile").Value
```

How can I get the actual telephone number?

Answer (score 0):

The class for the attribute was not generated correctly

```
public partial class enterprisePersonTel
```

{

```
private string teltypeField;

private string valueField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string teltype
{
    get
    {
        return this.teltypeField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.teltypeField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
**[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
public string Value
{
    get
    {
        return this.valueField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.valueField = value;
    }
}**
```

}
 The ** part of the text was missing when using paste as class in Visual studio.